# Python: Making post.file.url unique for image and video files

Tags: python, django, image, if-statement, video

Ive been working on a social media website where you can upload images and videos and follow other users.

I managed to upload and display uploaded files to the website.

I used FileField to load the image and video files, but when I implement it in my Template it shows both spaces, because there both using the same source url {{ source.file.url }}

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    file =  models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y-%m-%d')
```

feeds.html

```
{% if post.file.url %}
    <video class="video-context" width="500px" height="500px" controls>
      <source src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  {% endif %}



  {% if post.file.url %}
  <img class="image-context" src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="image/jpg" type="image/jpeg">
  {% endif %}
```

heres a sreenshot [empty video player over img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40snv.png)

I tried the `if endswith` form:

```
{% if file.endswith .mp4 %}
    <video class="video-context" width="500px" height="500px" controls>
      <source src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  {% endif %}
  {% if file.endswith .jpg/jpeg %}
    <img class="image-context" src="{{ post.file.url }}">
  {% endif %}
```

But it didn't work.

How can I just display the file thats uploaded. How can I make the {{ post.file.url }} unique for image and video, so its easier to difference?

How is it possible to difference the upload types, but still using FileField?

Answer (score 0):

Django templates filter "endswith" doesn't give you the extension of the file in your filefield. Instead, it gives the last character of an object, so in your case, it will be returning 4 if the file is a video type or it will return g if file is an image.

You want to get the extension of the uploaded and unfortunately, there is no filter for that in Django templates.

You need to create a function in your models that will return your file-type/extension.

Models.py

```
import os

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    file =  models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y-%m-%d')

    def extension(self):
        title, extension = os.path.splitext(self.file.name)
        return extension
```

Then in your templates, you can get the extension through this code...

```
{% for post in posts %}

   {% if post.extension == '.mp4'%}
      <video class="video-context" width="500px" height="500px" controls>
         <source src="{{ post.file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
   {% elif post.extension == '.jpg' or post.extension == '.jpeg' %}
      <img class="image-context" src="{{ post.file.url }}">
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can have all sorts of methods on a model to make your life and project easy.

Comment: Thank You for your Answer, it didn't worked for me tough. Even after migration. I think ist because the name: title isn't colorful, its gets darked out.

Comment: Try it now, I have tested it and its working without any issue

Comment: I tried your updated Version and it worked. I am so thankful for your Help. I ve been looking for solution the whole week, Than you so much.